Multiple selects but I also need to add another join
I have the following query which gives me an output below but I'd also like to add an extra part to it that converts one of the outputs to that from a different table. .
SELECT oc.card_number,
       opt.oper_date AS "TRANSACTION_DATE",
       op.account_number,
       CASE vf.sttl_currency
         WHEN '840' THEN
          'USD'
       END AS "SOURCE_AMOUNT_CURRENCY",
       CASE opt.oper_type
         WHEN 'OPTP0000' THEN
          -vf.sttl_amount
         ELSE
          vf.sttl_amount
       END AS "SOURCE_AMOUNT",
       op.auth_code,
       opt.mcc,
       opt.terminal_number AS "TERMINAL_ID",
       vf.pos_terminal_cap,
       vf.pos_entry_mode,
       opt.oper_type,
       opt.part_key AS "CAPTURE_DATE",
       opt.oper_amount AS "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT",
       opt.oper_currency AS "TRANSACTION_CURRENCY",
       opt.merchant_name,
       opt.merchant_country,
       opt.clearing_sequence_num,
       opt.clearing_sequence_count,
       CASE opt.oper_type
         WHEN 'OPTP0000' THEN
          '05-PURCHASE'
         WHEN 'OPTP0020' THEN
          '06-CREDIT VOUCHER'
         ELSE
          'other'
       END AS Transaction_Type
  FROM opr_operation   opt,
       opr_participant op,
       opr_card        oc,
       vis_fin_message vf
 WHERE op.oper_id = opt.id
   AND opt.id = vf.id
   AND opt.clearing_sequence_num > 1
   AND opt.part_key >= '28-MAR-24'
   AND op.card_id = vf.card_id
   AND op.participant_type = 'PRTYISS'
   AND oc.oper_id = opt.id
   AND opt.msg_type IN ('MSGTPAMC', 'MSGTPACC');

OUTPUT:
"CARD_NUMBER"   "TRANSACTION_DATE"  "ACCOUNT_NUMBER"    "SOURCE_AMOUNT_CURRENCY"    "SOURCE_AMOUNT" "AUTH_CODE" "MCC"   "TERMINAL_ID"   "POS_TERMINAL_CAP"  "POS_ENTRY_MODE"    "OPER_TYPE" "CAPTURE_DATE"  "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT"    "TRANSACTION_CURRENCY"  "MERCHANT_NAME" "MERCHANT_COUNTRY"  "CLEARING_SEQUENCE_NUM" "CLEARING_SEQUENCE_COUNT"   "TRANSACTION_TYPE"
"1234567891234567"  26-MAR-24   "004000485011"  "USD"   -2020   "735762"    "5734"  "TERMID01"  "9" "01"    "OPTP0000"  28-MAR-24   2020    "060"   "ACQUIRER NAME            " "060"   2   2   "05-PURCHASE"

But, What I'd like to do is for opt.merchant_country to use the values from another table called alpha_country.
In the alpha_country table, column 'C' - 'CODE' contains the 3 digit numeric values that match the values returned from opt.merchant_country and in column 'F' it contains the 2 digit alpha values. And I want to return the 2 digit alpha values in my query. So in my example, I'd like '060' to be displayed as 'BM'
This is the data held in alpha_country :
"ID"    "SEQNUM"    "CODE"  "NAME"  "CURR_CODE" "ALPHA_COUNTRY_CODE"    
1          1        "060"   "BMU"     "060"          "BM"   

I'm totally stuck and looked at doing joins but I think I'm now way over my ability so any help would be great please.

JOIN's are now for over 30 years sql standard, so you should also start using it

Hi, yes, I appreciate that. I'm not really a user of sql and I've managed to get this far (with the help of others on here) and this is the last piece of the jigsaw for me to give me an output from some internal testing. I know its not the best already but it almost gives me what I'll need it for.

also we need a [mre] see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Just join the extra table. Ignoring all the irrelevant columns, your query would be:
SELECT opt.merchant_country,
       a.alpha_country_code
FROM   opr_operation opt
       INNER JOIN opr_participant op
       ON op.oper_id = opt.id
       INNER JOIN opr_card oc
       ON oc.oper_id = opt.id
       INNER JOIN vis_fin_message vf
       ON     opt.id = vf.id
          AND op.card_id = vf.card_id
       INNER JOIN alpha_country a
       ON opt.merchant_country = a.code
WHERE  opt.clearing_sequence_num > 1
AND    opt.part_key >= DATE '2024-03-28'
AND    opt.msg_type IN ('MSGTPAMC', 'MSGTPACC')
AND    op.participant_type = 'PRTYISS';

